# How to enable inlay hints in Visual Studio Code Like JetBrains code editors in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, productivity-power-tools

So, I want this kind feature in Jetbrains code editors activated in Visual Studio Code
[image: Jetbrains Editor]

Enabled something like this in settings.json

[image: my settings.json]

but, nothing changed at all

[image: My VsCode]

How to enable inlay hints VS Code?

Answer (score 3):

My answer is probably late, but below is code that may help enable inlay hints support for Dart & Flutter in VS Code:

```
"[dart]": {
    "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "on"
}
```

PS: The above code should be pasted into your settings.json.

Answer (score 0):

This vscode [extension by MrChetan](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MrChetan.phpstorm-parameter-hints-in-vscode) gave me closer to my quest for this feature.